# _include in hapi fhir

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

Currently I am developing a FHIR Search API using HAPI FHIR (Java).

In the FHIR resource [MedicationRequest](https://hl7.org/fhir/medicationrequest.html) in HAPI FHIR (Java), I want to include the [Medication](https://hl7.org/fhir/medication.html) resource inline under [`MedicationRequest.medication[x]`](https://hl7.org/fhir/medicationrequest-definitions.html#MedicationRequest.medication_x_), instead of as a Reference. I have provided a snippet below.

```
//code
@IncludeParam(allow = { "MedicationRequest:medication" }) Set<Include> theIncludes 


// url
/MedicationRequest?_include=MedicationRequest:medication&status=stopped,active
```

However, when I hit the url the response does not include the Medication resource inline.

If I use `_include=*`, then I get the desired outcome. Medication is included inline, along with the other References.

```
// code
@IncludeParam(allow = { "*" }) Set<Include> theIncludes

// url
/MedicationRequest?_include=*&status=stopped,active
```

Can anyone please help me in understanding why I am not getting desired outcome when I am using `_include=MedicationRequest:medication`?

Comment: Is it because it is not called "MedicationRequest:medication"? You could confirm the name used by looking at the value you receive when you use _include=*

Answer (score 0):

`_include=MedicationRequest:medication` is the appropriate usage.

`medication[x]` refers to either:

- medicationCodeableConcept
- medicationReference

My best guess is you're attempting to `_include` a `Medication` resource that does not have a globally resolvable id set.

Without a globally resolvable id, HAPI FHIR will generate a locally resolvable id and include the locally resolvable `Medication` under `MedicationRequest.contained`.

Fix by setting an id and using a globally resolvable reference, i.e. `medicationReference.reference: Medication/myMed1` instead of `medicationReference.reference: #myMed1`

See:

- [2.2.2 References in Server Code](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/model/references.html#references-in-server-code)
- [4.5.14 Resource Includes (_include)](https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/server_plain/rest_operations_search.html#resource-includes-include)

---

URL: http://test.fhir.org/r4/MedicationRequest?_id=medrx0311&_include=MedicationRequest:medication

Returns a bundle with only the `MedicationRequest`. `Medication` is contained at `MedicationRequest.contained`.

```
{
  "resourceType" : "MedicationRequest",
  "id" : "medrx0311",
  ...
  "contained" : [
    {
      "resourceType" : "Medication",
      "id" : "med0316",
  ...
  "medicationReference" : {
      "reference" : "#med0316"
},
```

The `medicationReference.reference: #med0316` is not global; therefore, it's contained.

URL http://test.fhir.org/r4/MedicationRequest?_id=medrx002&_include=MedicationRequest:medication

Returns a bundle with both the `MedicationRequest` and `Medication`.

```
{
  "resourceType" : "MedicationRequest",
  "id" : "medrx002",
... 
  "medicationReference" : {
  "reference" : "Medication/med0316",
  "display" : "prescribed medication"
},
...
{
  "resourceType" : "Medication",
  "id" : "med0316",
```

Here, the appropriate global id `medicationReference.reference: Medication/med0316` is used, so Medication is listed as a separate entry in the bundle.

Comment: Thank you for explaining @rmharrison . i added setBundleInclusionRule(BundleInclusionRule.BASED_ON_RESOURCE_PRESENCE); in my code and after that it was working fine